# C++ crashing when attempting to assign a new value to a pointer array pointing to chars

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, 2d

So I hope to convert uppercase characters to lower case by a simple addition of 32 to the char's value, which essentially gives it's lower case equivalent.

In the main I declare the pointer array and assign 3 words:

```
int main()
{
    char *dictionary[10];
    dictionary[0] = "aUto";
    dictionary[1] = "caR";
    dictionary[2] = "Door";
    int arrayCount = 3;
    upperCase(dictionary, &arrayCount);
}
```

in the function I attempt to convert:

```
void upperCase(char *dictionary[], int *arrayCount)
{
    cout << "In upperCase\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int k = 0; dictionary[i][k] != '\0'; k++)
        {
            if (dictionary[i][k] < 97 && dictionary[i][k] > 64) // If     capital is less than the value of 'a' (97)
            {
                dictionary[i][k] += 32;
            }
            else
                cout << "Not a capital\n";
        }
}
```

The program crashes at dictionary[i][k] += 32;
I am attempting to replace the character in the string(which is pointed to by the elements of the array). Even converting the letter first does not work.
Ex: dictionary[i][k] = 'a'; 
Still crashes my program.
Running Eclipse C++ on windows

Comment: You have an array of pointers to string literals. Attempting to modify the string literals gives undefined behavior. As a side-note, the compiler already has `std::tolower` for this job.

Comment: The tag `dynamic-arrays` is not appropriate.

Comment: If you're just trying to get a little practice fooling around with `char *` then that's perfectly fine. But for virtually all normal string processing in C++ you will want to use `std::string`.

Comment: BTW, it's probably *much*, *much* more efficient to use `std::tolower`, as it would use a lookup table and no branch instructions. There is no reason to write this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this is probably covered in the comments by now. Just looked. Yup. I got busy before I could post. Anyway, here's a break-down of the problem:

```
char *dictionary[10];
```

This is cool.

```
dictionary[0] = "aUto";
```

This is not cool. "aUto" is a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal). A string of constant values. How this is stored is up to the compiler. You can read it, but you should not count on being able to write it. Treat is as though defined as `const char *` because, as far as the language is concerned, it is `const char *`.

Why this is not cool is OP assigns a `const char *` to a `char *`. Assigning a pointer to constant to a pointer to non constant should generate at least a warning. Best to turn up the warning level in your compiler to catch this sort of error early. In g++ and similar, I like `-Wall`, `-Wextra`, and a side order of `-pedantic`. In MSVC, navigate Properties->C/C++->General and play with Warning Level. EnableAllWarnings looks like a good place to start.

Now that the constant values are referenced by a non constant pointer, the compiler has no clue that the next bit is likely fatal.

```
dictionary[i][k] += 32;
```

Attempts to add 32 to a character, that part is fine, and then store the result into a non-writable location. This is not allowed, but the exact handling of attempting the impossible is up to the compiler. You got a program crash, which is quite nice of the compiler. The program could have kept running, smashed some other memory space, and died later, giving you no clue what actually happened and what to debug.

How to make those strings not constant:

1. Use [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) rather than char *. In C++ this is by far the better option. And while you're at it, use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of the array.
2. But this smells like homework and you may not be allowed to use std::string. In that case, allocate storage and copy the string literals into the storage so that they have real, modifiable memory backing them.

Coding style notes:

Rather than using numeric values like 97, use the character 'a'. It works the same and your intent is much easier to determine. Better save yourself all the trouble and use [std::tolower](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower).

There also is a neat trick you can do with [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), std::string, and std::tolower to remove the bulk of the upperCase function. Experiment a bit and you'll find it.
Correction (and I always seem to catch myself on this one): use tolower, not std::tolower because std::tolower's locale overload makes it ambiguous which std::tolower you want.

This:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

Is kind of silly. You passed in arrayCount. You might as well use it and save yourself from confusion if you ever change the number of items in the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < *arrayCount; i++)
```

Comment: You really broke it down well, thank you very much. Yes it is homework, and we cannot use the string functions. It's an attempt to help understand fundamentals.

Answer (score -1):

If you're allowed to use C++, then you could instead:

1. Use STL
2. Use vectors, usually much easier to handle for these types of things
3. Use Stringstream (or streams in general)

It's just an idea though. But your code certainly looks more like a C question (which would rather use malloc to allocate dynamic memory) instead of a C++ one.

Also, are you sure that the `dictionary[i][k] += 32` operation is really doing what you think it should do? Usually crashes in those types of code mean that your pointer is pointing to an unallocated/invalid place.